# Draft is still saved even after question already posted

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, draft

Steps to reproduce:

1. Post a question
2. Press the ask question button again
3. See "you have a saved draft. Discard or resume?" pop-up
4. Press resume
5. See the question you previously posted appear as a draft

It seems like this is an easy fix; just clear the draft when the submit question button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sadly a race condition I haven't been able to recreate on my end, but I put in logic that should fix it for version 0.1.90 coming out around midnight UTC. Let me know if you see it again and I'll remove my [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Alright, thanks! Will test next time I want to post a question :-P

Comment: I somehow don't think it'll take too long before you find another bug to post, being able to test this one :)